# Python 3 match values based on column name similarity

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the following form:

| Year 1 Grade | Year 2 Grade | Year 3 Grade | Year 4 Grade | Year 1 Students | Year 2 Students | Year 3 Students | Year 4 Students |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | 70 | 80 | 100 | 20 | 32 | 18 | 25 |

I would like to somehow transpose this table to the following format:

| Year | Grade | Students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 20 |
| 2 | 70 | 32 |
| 3 | 80 | 18 |
| 4 | 100 | 25 |

I created a list of years and initiated a new dataframe with the "year" column. I was thinking of matching the year integer to the column name containing it in the original DF, match and assign the correct value, but got stuck there.

Comment: !invoke @sammywemmy for `pivot_longer` option

Comment: Maybe I should do a canonical:)

Comment: @sammywemmy for sure you should!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Feel free to ask questions about how it works.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ["Year 1 Grade", "Year 2 Grade", "Year 3 Grade" , "Year 4 Grade",
        "Year 1 Students", "Year 2 Students", "Year 3 Students", "Year 4 Students"]
vals = [60,70,80,100,20,32,18,25]
vals = [[v] for v in vals]
df = pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,v in zip(cols,vals)})

grades = df.filter(like="Grade").T.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0:"Grades"})
students = df.filter(like="Student").T.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={0:"Students"})
pd.concat([grades,students], axis=1)
```

Comment: This one was very flexible for me to solve the use case above along with other ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need a manual reshaping using a `split` of the Index into a MultiIndex:

```
out = (df
 .set_axis(df.columns.str.split(expand=True), axis=1) # make MultiIndex
 .iloc[0]                                             # select row as Series
 .unstack()                                           # unstack Grade/Students
 .droplevel(0)                                        # remove literal "Year"
 .rename_axis('Year')                                 # set index name
 .reset_index()                                       # index to column
)
```

output:

```
  Year  Grade  Students
0    1     60        20
1    2     70        32
2    3     80        18
3    4    100        25
```

Or using [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from `janitor`:

```
# pip install pyjanitor

import janitor

out = (df.pivot_longer(
           names_to = ('ignore', 'Year', '.value'), 
           names_sep = ' ')
         .drop(columns='ignore')
       )

out 
  Year  Grade  Students
0    1     60        20
1    2     70        32
2    3     80        18
3    4    100        25
```

The `.value` determines which parts of the sub labels in the columns are retained; the labels are split apart by `names_sep`, which can be a string or a regex. Another option is by using a regex, with `names_pattern` to split and reshape the columns:

```py
df.pivot_longer(names_to = ('Year', '.value'), 
                names_pattern = r'.+(\d)\s(.+)')
  Year  Grade  Students
0    1     60        20
1    2     70        32
2    3     80        18
3    4    100        25
```

Comment: For some reason I get `Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex` in the rename_axis step

Comment: @Nashh comment the last two lines and check that you have a DataFrame

Comment: indeed I have a DataFrame

Comment: Then provide the constructor of the input. This works fine with the example

Answer (score 0):

I came up with these. grades here are your first row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(grades) # your dataframe without columns

grades = np.array(df.iloc[0]).reshape(4,2) # extract the first row, turn it into an array and reshape it to 4*2
new_df = pd.DataFrame(grades).reset_index()

new_df.columns = ['Year', 'Grade', 'Students'] # rename the columns
```