# Combine similar DataFrame columns and stack values

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, I have a dataframe that looks as such:

| abc | def | ghi | abc | def | ghi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 78 | 56 | 7 | 45 |

Is there a way to combine the columns that have the same name and create a new row for each set of values? Example:

| abc | def | ghi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 78 |
| 56 | 7 | 45 |

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a MultiIndex with help of [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
(df
 .set_axis(pd.MultiIndex
             .from_arrays([df.columns,
                           df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)
                             .cumcount()]), axis=1)
 .stack()
 .droplevel(0)
)
```

Output:

```
   abc  def  ghi
0    2    4   78
1   56    7   45
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.groupby(level=0, axis='columns')` to assign a cumulative count and then perform a transformation based on that.

```py
import pandas as pd

new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).cumcount()])

out = df.set_axis(new_cols, axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

print(out)
   abc  def  ghi
0    2    4   78
1   56    7   45
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an alternative to other answers with `melt`:

```
out = (df.melt(var_name='col', value_name='val')
         .assign(idx=lambda x: x.groupby('col').cumcount())
         .pivot('idx', 'col', 'val').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print(out)

# Output
   abc  def  ghi
0    2    4   78
1   56    7   45
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(names_to = '.value', names_pattern = '(.+)')

   abc  def  ghi
0    2    4   78
1   56    7   45
```

In the above solution, the `.value` determines which parts of the column labels remain as headers - the labels are determined by the groups in the regular expression in `names_pattern`.

Another option would be to pass the names of the new columns to `names_to`, while passing a list of matching regular expressions to `names_pattern` :

```py
df.pivot_longer(names_to = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], 
                names_pattern = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])

   abc  def  ghi
0    2    4   78
1   56    7   45
```

Comment: I tried to invoke you on [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166964/python-3-match-values-based-on-column-name-similarity#comment129221672_73166964). I hope [I used it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167299/16343464) :p

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.T.rename_axis('col1',axis=1).assign(group=lambda dd:(dd.index=='abc').cumsum())\
    .pivot_table(index='group',columns='col1',values=0)
```

```
col1  abc  def  ghi
                   
1       2    4   78
2      56    7   45
```